# Finding determinants with properties given minimal information

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be $2 \times 2$ matrices, where $\det(A)=2, \det(B)=3$. Find

$$\det(B^{T} A^{-3}(2BA)^2)$$

I know that $\det(B)$ and $\det(B^{T})$ are the same so it stays $3$.

I don't quite know how to proceed after that.

Comment: That second line is not clear, can you add some parentheses to clarify?

Comment: I see somebody has edited it.  Looks plausible, is that what you intended?

Comment: @user220177 I made some edits to make your question more readable. Let me know if this is what you meant.

Comment: ya thats what i meant

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\det(B^TA^{-3}(2BA)^2) = \det(B^T)\det(A)^{-3}\det(2BA)^2,$$ and $\det(2BA) = 4\det(BA)$ because the matrices are $2\times 2$.

Comment: for det(A)^-3    does it follow the formula det(A)^-1 and the answer to the power of 3 ? which gives me 8/13?

Comment: Note: $$\det(A)^{-3} = \frac{1}{\det(A)^3},$$ and you know that $\det(A)=2$.

Comment: ok so so far i have (3)x(1/8) as for the 4 det(BA) = det(B) det(A)?

Comment: It is not true that $4\det(BA) = \det(B)\det(A)$. You just have to look at the expression in my hint and plug in values. Can you do that?

Comment: well is it det(B) = 3 & det(A) = 2 so det(BA) = 6?

Comment: That is what $\det(BA) = \det(B)\det(A)$ means.

Comment: ok so it becomes 6 x 4 = 24  and now all we have to do is multiply 3x(1/8)x24 = 72

Comment: oh no wait scratch that last that gives 9